# exported method and unexported methods in Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two functions defined in a component. foo() is defined just within `<script>`, and fooExported() is defined in the body of export default {}

My understanding is that functions inside export default {} can be accessed in the template, so it sounds the "unexported" function foo() is a "private" function only available within the `<script>` scope (Is this correct?). What other difference do they have?

Also I'm trying to access this.$data in the "unexported" method but it shows undefined error. Is it not possible to access the data?

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
function foo(){
    console.log(this.$data.message)  // error: 'this' is undefined.
}
const bar = 123

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      message: 'MyMessage'
    }
  },
  methods: {
      fooExported(){ 
          console.log(this.$data.message)  // this works.
      }
   }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a component in a [single-file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) `.vue` file. This means that everything inside the `default` object is passed directly to the constructor method for a new Vue instance. Vue knows to automatically set the reference to `this` in any method defined within the `methods` object.

Your `foo` method is never handled by Vue, and the reference to `this` does not point to the Vue instance in the context of that function.

If you want your `foo` method to have a reference to the `message` data property, you could call the method from the `created` hook and pass the `this.message` as a parameter:

```
created() {
  foo(this.message);
}
```

---

*side note: as you can see above, you can reference data properties directly from `this`; you don't need to go through `this.$data`.*